# Height: Auto in Internet Explorer 8 and below

Tags: image, css, responsive-design

Moving towards responsive design, I'm using %s for images, e.g.:

```
#example img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 690px; // Width of the image uploaded.
}
```

This works great, except in Internet Explorer 8 and below. Is this due to `height: auto` being part of CSS3, which is only supported by IE9 onwards?

And the most important part... any suggestions on a way around this problem? The only thing I can think of so far is to give it a max-height.

Thanks

Answer (score 57):

Try this:

```
img {
  width: inherit;  /* Make images fill their parent's space. Solves IE8. */
  max-width: 100%; /* Add !important if needed. */
  height: auto;    /* Add !important if needed. */
}
```

OR:

```
img { max-width:100%; height: auto; } /* Enough everywhere except IE8. */
@media \0screen {img { width: auto }} /* Prevent height distortion in IE8. */
```

Both solutions work. The difference is that `width:inherit` makes images fill their parent's space whereas `width:auto` maxes them at their actual dimensions. See **[fit.css](https://github.com/ryanve/fit/blob/master/fit.css)**

Comment: Only thing working for me is: `@media \0screen {img { width: auto }} /* Prevent height distortion in IE8. */`

Comment: This solves a lot more than just IE 8. Fixed an issue in IE 11 for me. What a mess.

Comment: This solved it for me in IE11 too. At first adding "width: inherit" didn't fix it. Thanks to ryanve's explanation (SO HELPFUL!!!) I realized I needed to modify the image's container and so I gave it "width: 100%" too. I have an image at the top and want text on top of it, so here's the code I ended up with: .containerBox {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

and then for the image:
.img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  padding: auto;
  width: inherit;
}