# html site not working in internet explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I just made a website awhile ago and have been testing in chrome and firefox mostly.

I put the site online today and discovered its completely not functional with Internet Explorer! I went to wc3 validator but I can't see anything that would cause such catastrophic failure.

I'm panicking about this. Can anyone help?

It happens on the following site: http://msc32.cmsmotion.com

Comment: You probably want to be specific with what is wrong.  Is it just the image?  Or is the JavaScript bad too?  I would guess that is why it was down voted.

Comment: How about adding a link to your website so we can see what's wrong?

Comment: I did, http://msc32.cmsmotion.com

I tried modifying the image dimensions but that didn't correct the problem. I hate internet explorer

Comment: @TravisPessetto I downvoted because it is a bad question. "its completely not functional with Internet Explorer" Isn't a error message nor a problem description.

Comment: Sorry I should be way more specific, I was just a bit shocked. First problem is, the image isn't showing up on the main page. I'd like to fix that if I could

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is because you are trying to do funky stuff with the width and/or the height of the image in IE. IE doesn't like that. You will see that if you set the height and width to "real" values e.g. set both to 400 it will work.

Not part of the answer, but it is considered bad practice to use inline style attributes.

Comment: Thank you so much, was having a meltdown

Answer (score 2):

Setting your image dimensions to auto is your problem. Check this out: [Height: Auto in Internet Explorer 8 and below](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8610077/1315694)

Comment: Just checked this and it's correct.  Doesn't work with IE9 either.

Comment: I changed the settings to match those but the problem remains. Can't seem to figure it out

Comment: Have you tried adding it in css as noted in the linked post?  Just adding it inline in your image with IE's developer tools: style=" width: 100%; height: auto;" and removing your height and width attributes displays properly.  <img alt="Header" src="images/space.jpg" complete="complete" style="width: 100%; height: auto;"/>.  FTR, inline styles are not preferred. Tack them in your stylesheet.

Answer (score -2):

Well, what a shame.. I suggest you do it again and test only in IE, this way you save time.. generally, if it works in IE, then it works in other browsers.. Also, don't use Tables.. unless you're very familiar with its nature.. Tables usually work different in every browser

Comment: Tables work pretty much the same across browsers these days, if you use standard HTML with a browser that's not being thrown into quirks mode.  (There are other reasons for not using tables for layout, but this isn't one of them.)  And IE has enough compatibility issues, and stuff specific to it, that stuff that "works" in IE breaks in other browsers if you don't keep cross-browser compatibility in mind.