# 100% inline svg width not working in IE11

Tags: svg, internet-explorer-11

I have a basic inline svg setup

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 25.51 25.51">
    <rect id="a1" x="0.5" y="0.5" width="25.51" height="25.51"/>
</svg>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ahsnurwf/7/)

In any browser the svg takes the full width, except IE11. The css looks like

```
svg {
    stroke: #000;
    stroke-width: 2px;
}

svg rect {
    fill: red;
}
```

I've tried adding `width: 100%` and `display: block` to the **svg** but that didn't help. Any suggestion how I can make the svg 100% in width in IE11?

Comment: Have you tried `width: inherit, max-width: 100%` proposed at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610077/height-auto-in-internet-explorer-8-and-below ?

Comment: I've added the css properties [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ahsnurwf/10/) but the result is still the same

Comment: Example workaround using linked dup solution: https://jsfiddle.net/ahsnurwf/13/

Comment: check, the canvas fixes the issue in IE11 :)

Answer (score 2):

By default, the attribute `preserveAspectRatio = "xMinYMin meet"`

Set the value of this attribute `none`

```css
svg {
    stroke: #000;
    stroke-width: 2px;
}

svg rect {
    fill: red;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 30 30" preserveAspectRatio = "none">
    <rect id="a1" x="0.5" y="0.5" width="25.51" height="25.51"/>
</svg>
```

Now the width of svg is 100% in IE11.

But the proportions are not respected and the square is stretched to a rectangle in consultation with the proportions of the browser window. To have a rectangle, you need to set the viewport SVG for example:

```
width="900" height="900"
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="900" height="900" viewBox="0 0 30 30" >
    <rect id="a1" x="0.5" y="0.5" width="25" height="25" stroke-width="2px" stroke="#000" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: As far as I understand your solution, it will not work in a responsive setting, meaning you don't know the width, so you need to set it to `100%`, is that correct?

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri https://caniuse.com/#search=svg "IE9-11 desktop & mobile don't properly scale SVG files. Adding height, width, viewBox, and CSS rules seem to be the best workaround."  This is a known IE bug and installing a 100% viewport will not help